# how to insert Indian language Telugu charactes in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to store Indian language(Telugu) in my database table.But it is displaying ???? while inserting Telugu data into my table.I have verified some thing like below

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘character_set_system’;
```

It displaying the output like `Character_set_system| UTF8`.

After that i have altered my talbe

```
alter table lang modify characters varchar(12) character set utf8;
```

still do i need anything for that.

Comment: how do you enter the data? by hand in the terminal? by program? in any way you must make sure that the terminal or program use also utf8

Comment: present i copied the data from some where and paste in my insert query.

Answer (score 2):

Append `characterEncoding=UTF-8` at the end of the database URL like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Before that set `utf8_general_ci` in your table column.

Answer (score 1):

use the Collation in DB for the particular field and set utf8_general_ci.

Comment: how to set collation for a particular field.

Comment: I have create table like                                         CREATE TABLE `lang` (
  `characters` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin

Comment: after create table, go into the Db. select table -> then go to structure.

There you can see the collaction for the particular field..
now you can set up.

Comment: yes its diplayed like the collate for my column characters is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: after i have setted collate to utf8_general_ci  also it displaying ??? inserting telugu text.