# how to insert Telugu characters into mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have inserted Telugu text through Toad interface,it is working.But when i execute same insert and select query on MySQL command line it displaying ???.is there any problem with MySQL command line.And i have enabled `character set` with `utf8`,`collate` with `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Don't clone post [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586397/how-to-store-indian-language-like-telugu-hindi-in-mysql-database), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546142/how-to-insert-indian-language-telugu-charactes-in-mysql) and this one, just post one and give all the info there

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database with utf-8 datatype. It will store any type of value. Kindly sure that, collision and char type must be utf-8.

try my this answer -

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
your insert query.......
result = queryExeution;
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $UserDetailSqlVal);

Comment: i have setted mydatabase with utf8 and character set,collation is utf8.now also it displaying ??? at the time of insertion.

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); your query....... $result = queryExeution; mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $result);

you can apply thess two utf-8 conversion syntax on insert and select sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your table collation to utf8

mysql query SET CHARACTER SET utf8

or use php function htmlentities